# Formatting long dynamic text in UITextView using NSRange defined by special characters in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, text, dynamic, formatting

I have the product description pages generated dynamically. They contain long text with headlines and paragraphs of text which is placed in `UITextView`. I want to make headlines be displayed in bold.

Can use special characters to define `NSRange` which which will be set to bold style.
Something similar like `<b>...</b>` in `HTML`?
I know how to format range from character 5 to character 15, but since it's dynamic text this is not possible.
Im looking for solution in `SWIFT` on `Xcode 6.3`